# mysql hour() method in mongodb?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

Whats the simplest way of extracting the hour integer from a time string (format "23:21:00") in MongoDB?

```
hour("23:21:00") // 23
```

I have the function implemented and working in mysql, but it seems that its not that straightforward in Mongo.

Am I resigned to converting the time into a date object, and then using Mongo's $hour aggregation pipeline function?

Comment: `$substr: [ "$hour", 0, 2 ]`

Comment: @Xatenev this will produce string not int

Answer (score 1):

Use the $where
db.collection.find({$where : function() { return this.date.getHours() == 23} })